# Java - Scanner throws Exception

Tags: java

I changed my program from *String variables* to *StringBuffer*.
I used a Scanner in this program before and the first one is working as it should, only the second one is making troubles.

```
Scanner sb = new Scanner(System.in);
replaceFind = replaceFind.append(sb.nextLine());
sb.close();
```

That's the code of my scanner itself.

```
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(text), replaceFind = new StringBuffer();
```

And the lower one is my variable which is used.

At last I'll post the exception that is thrown automatically:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
>       at com.stoeger.StringUebung.insertNewText(StringUebung.java:143)
>       at com.stoeger.StringUebung.(StringUebung.java:45)
>       at com.stoeger.TheMain.main(TheMain.java:6)

Here's the second Scanner I used, which is working fine:

```
String find = null;
Scanner sb = new Scanner(System.in);
find = sb.nextLine();
sb.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of my problem:
I had 2 Scanners in my program, and that throws the exception.

I put my Scanner as global variable (private) and just closed it in the end of the program, now I can use it normally.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is from sb.nextLine(). You can check sb.hasNextLine() before calling sb.nextLine(), this must avoid the exception you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sb = new (System.in);
StringBuffer replaceFind = new StringBuffer();

while (sb.hasNextLine()) 
    replaceFind = replaceFind.append(sb.nextLine());

sb.close();
```